# expl3 outputting sequence of plists

Tags: expl3

Suppose, I have a sequence of 2 plists:

```
(
{
      1 => 2,
      3 => 4
},
{
      5 => 6,
      hello => 8
}
)
```

I am traversing through the sequence and want to output only plists, containing the key "hello". I created this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%sequence definition
\clist_new:N\l_my_clist

%plist1 definition
\prop_new:N \prop_list_a
\prop_put:Nnn \prop_list_a {1}{2}
\prop_put:Nnn \prop_list_a {3}{4}

%plist2 definition
\prop_new:N \prop_list_b
\prop_put:Nnn \prop_list_b {5}{6}
\prop_put:Nnn \prop_list_b {hello}{8}

%putting plists to sequence
\clist_set:Nn \l_my_clist {\prop_list_a, \prop_list_b}

%output loop
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_my_clist
{
  \prop_get:NnNTF #1 {hello} \var
  {
    \prop_map_inline:Nn #1
    {
      [##1] ~[##2]\\
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

It outputs this:

[image]

1. Why did the comma appear?
2. How to get rid of it?
3. How to use `\var` in `\prop_get:NnNTF`? What was it designed for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used `\prop_get:NnNTF` but have not given a false branch in your code, so you are getting odd effects. You seem to want something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

%plist1 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_a_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_a_prop { 1 } { 2 }
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_a_prop { 3 } { 4 }

%plist2 definition
\prop_new:N \l_list_b_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { 5 } { 6 }
\prop_put:Nnn \l_list_b_prop { hello } { 8 }

%putting plists to sequence
\seq_new:N \l_my_seq
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_a_prop }
\seq_push:Nn \l_my_seq { \l_list_b_prop }
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_my_seq
  {
    \prop_get:NnNT #1 { hello } \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \prop_map_inline:Nn #1 { [ ##1 ] ~ [ ##2 ] \\ }
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

(I've tided up variable names and used a sequence rather than a comma list: the latter are really meant mainly for using with 'user level' input.)

The idea of `\prop_get:NnN(TF)` is that it recovers the *value* associated with the *key* and stores it in the token list. You can then use it:

```
\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { foo } { bar }
\prop_get:NnNTF \l_my_prop { foo } \l_tmpa_tl
  {
    % \l_tmpa_tl is set to 'bar' and can be used, for example:
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    % \l_tmpa_tl is not in a defined state
  }
```

Comment: You didn't use the false branch either in `\prop_get:NnNT`, so  this was not the issue. It seems, that comma disappeared, because you used a sequence instead of clist. What was wrong with the clist?

Comment: @user4035 Note the missing F in NnNT which eliminates the need for a false branch.

Comment: @user4035 I didn't use a false branch as I used `\prop_get:NnNT` rather than `\prop_get:NnNTF`. Comma lists are more limited than sequences: they can't hold empty values, 'odd' input (for example commas!), _etc._ Sequences can do all of these things, and we can gain some speed in some internals as a result (`\seq_map_inline:Nn` is faster than `\clist_map_inline:Nn`, for example).